Problem setting the content property of the SfRichTextEditor dynamically in MAUI Hybrid App
I have linked sample project here where I can reproduce the issue -
CIllustrationPage.xaml has a BlazorWebView whose root component in CIllustration.razor
CIllustration.razor has a SfRichTextEditor whose content property should be dynamically set
In CIllustrationPage.xaml.cs constructor, if I set the parameters => they appear correctly in RichTextEditor
But my content is not yet available at this point.
public CIllustrationPage(/*CollegeCategoriesViewModel viewModel*/)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //I want to send the viewModel data to the component => BUT viewModel is not yet available
        //view model will be bound at a later stage and triggers OnBindingContextChanged
        
        rootComponent.Parameters =
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "RichTextContent",  "From Constructor"}
        };

        //simulating the viewmodel initialization
        BindingContext = "BINDING";
    }

So, I tried to set the parameters in OnBindingContextChanged method where my data is available.
[Here, I have simulated a delay to represent real data-fetch scenario]
protected override async void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        //await viewModel.Init();

        new Task(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            //viewModel.College.Details = @"<h1> College Information</h1>";
            var details = "From OnBindingContextChanged";

            rootComponent.Parameters =
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "RichTextContent",  details}
            };
        }).Start();
}

This newly set parameters are not notified to the RichTextEditor which is as below. The rich text editor still displays "From Constructor", instead of "From OnBindingContextChanged"
<div id="Editor" >
<SfRichTextEditor Readonly=true Value=@RichTextContent>
    <RichTextEditorToolbarSettings Enable=false></RichTextEditorToolbarSettings>
</SfRichTextEditor>

@code {
[Parameter]
public string RichTextContent { get; set; }
}


please post the relative code

@Jason As mentioned in the description, the sample project can be found at -
https://github.com/manjunath-vadigeri/ParameterIssue

The SO rules require relevant code to be included in the body of the post.

Sorry for not including the code snippet directly in the post earlier. I have edited the post to include relevant code.
